# How to get right landscape(90° or 270°) Rotation?

Tags: android, rotation

I´m trying to get the right landscape Rotation. What I have done until now:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Code to handle

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Log.i("RemoDroid", "Landscape");
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Log.i("RemoDroid", "portrait"); // 0
    }

}
```

So portrait is clear = 0°
But landscape can be 90° or 270°. How to find this out. 
Im looking for a smart solution if possible. I do not want to use Orientation-/Rotationmatrix and get oriantation of axis.

Do any one have a solution?

Comment: Why do you need to know the difference? In general I would expect any UI to work (look) the same in either landscape position.

Comment: I need to recalcute the touchevent cordinates. So i need the right Rotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Display.getOrientation()` which returns one of the following:

- `Surface.ROTATION_0`
- `Surface.ROTATION_90`
- `Surface.ROTATION_180`
- `Surface.ROTATION_270`

For me information see the [Android Display docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getOrientation%28%29).